# I am having trouble reading a recording file from my mobile using Librosa in the Flask API

Tags: python, audio-recording, flask-restful, librosa

I have created an Alphabet Recognition API using Flask. However, my model requires a .wav file input from a mobile device's recording on Android. Although I have read the file, Librosa is unable to load it because the format is unrecognized.

eror
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NeAzz.png)

my api code

```py
@app.route('/pred_alphabet', methods=['POST'])
def prediction():
    audio_file = request.files.get('audio_file')
    # audio_path = 'A-1.wav'
    y, sr = librosa.load(audio_file)
    X = np.mean(librosa.feature.mfcc(y=y,sr=sr,n_mfcc=40).T,axis=0)
    X=np.array(X)
    X=np.expand_dims(X,-1)
    #prediksi
    predictions = model.predict(X)
    # print(predictions)
    labels = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z']
    predicted_labels = [labels[np.argmax(pred)] for pred in predictions]
    mode = statistics.mode(predicted_labels)
    return jsonify ({'code':200,
        'result': str(mode)})
```

I have attempted to convert the file to a .wav format using ffmpeg, soundfile, and pydub, but the issue remains unsolved.

Comment: the question needs sufficient code for a minimal reproducible example:
https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: You should save the file to disk, and check whether it is actually a valid audio file at all.

Comment: How does the client side code look like?